# Can't open PDF through browser - Invalid Colorspace error

Tags: browser, adobe-reader

I have a PDF file which I'm trying to access through a web browser. Adobe Reader (version 9.4.0.195) starts loading it but then shows only a blank page and gives an error:

*There was an error processing a page. Invalid ColorSpace*

[image]

This happens with IE8/Firefox, in Chrome the files seem to open correctly.

If I click OK and save it to my computer then I can open the local file without any problems. It's also possible to uncheck "Display PDF in browser" setting in Adobe Reader's preferences and then it's possible to open it through the browsers (IE/FF). But I can't instruct every client who'd like to view it..

Is there something wrong with this specific file? What could be done to fix it? I only have this PDF and not the original document which was used to create it.

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem specific to that one PDF, but I'm really just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by opening the local file in Foxit PDF Editor and just re-saving without changing anything. Seems to be opening within all browsers now

Answer (score 0):

In Adobe reader go to edit/Preferences select Internet on the left side and uncheck Allow Fast Web View.

Comment: Then he wouldn't be able to preview other PDF's in his web browsers